# Spring AngularJS get request

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

I am trying to do pagination for my users list. I have an error "Bad request" when I try to use params in request. What can be the problem?

**UserController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{page}",params ={"size"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getList(@PathVariable("page") int page, @RequestParam("size") int size) {    
        List usersList = userService.getList(page, size);    
        ResponseEntity<List<User>> respEntity = null;    
        if(usersList.isEmpty()){
            respEntity =new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            return respEntity;
        }    
        respEntity =new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(usersList, HttpStatus.OK);    
        return respEntity;    
    }
```

**user_service.js**

```
fetchAllUsers: function(page, size) {
                return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/user/' + page, size)
                        .then(
                                function(response){
                                    console.log(response.data);
                                    console.table(response.data);
                                    return response.data;
                                }, 
                                function(errResponse){
                                    console.error('Error while fetching users');
                                    return $q.reject(errResponse);
                                }
                        );
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation of $http.get](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) says:

> get(url, [config]);
>
> [...]
>
> config (optional) Object Optional configuration object

You're passing the size as second argument, instead of a config object. The correct code is

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8080/user/' + page, {
    params: {
        size: size
    }
})...
```